# Wordpress comments email notification for authors

Tags: comments, users, email, notifications

I'm admin of a question and answers website in WordPress. All users are defined like authors.

I have the problem that when I approve a comment ( an answer to a question), the author receives too much personal information ( email address, ip, whois arin, links of: spam it, trash it, approve it, ) of other users by the comments notification email sent by WordPress.

Is there a way to modify this email sent to authors?

Answer (score 3):

The [`wp_notify_postauthor()` function is pluggable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L987) meaning that you can copy the code and paste it into a plugin file or theme functions file **keeping the same function name** and WordPress will use your version rather than its own. Edit your version of the function to send as much or as little information as you like.